# Could reduce max_result_window improve query performance?

Tags: elasticsearch

Can reducing the value of `index.max_result_window` improve query performance? For example, reducing it from 10000 to 1000.

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/company/_settings' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
> {
>   "index" : {
>     "max_result_window" : 1000
>   }
> }'
```

Why is it that even after reducing the value, the hits.total.value returned is still 10000?

```
"hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 10000,
            "relation": "gte"
        },
```

company index mapping

```
{
  "company" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "comWeb" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "curyName" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },        
        "hldIds" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "hldNames" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "analyzer" : "ik_max_word",
          "search_analyzer" : "ik_smart"
        },
        "id" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "induSmaPar" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },        
        "memberIds" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "memberNames" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "analyzer" : "ik_max_word",
          "search_analyzer" : "ik_smart"
        },        
        "name" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          },
          "analyzer" : "ik_max_word",
          "search_analyzer" : "ik_smart"
        },
        "offiAddr" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "operCond" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "orgAttrPar" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "orgChaStatus" : {
          "type" : "boolean"
        },
        "orgClaName" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "orgDele" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "orgDeleCode" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "orgDeleParName" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },        
        "orgEstDate" : {
          "type" : "date"
        },
        "orgMailAddr" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },                
        "orgStaPar" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "orgTel" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "province" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },        
        "regCap" : {
          "type" : "double"
        },
        "shortName" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },        
        "viewCount" : {
          "type" : "integer"
        },
        "weight" : {
          "type" : "byte"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

query

```
{
     "query": {
         "function_score": {
             "query": {
                 "bool": {
                     "should": [{
                             "match": {
                                 "name": {"query":"{{query_name}}","minimum_should_match":"4<85%"}
                             }
                         },
                         {
                             "match": {
                                 "shortName": {
                                     "query": "{{query_name}}",
                                     "boost": 2.9
                                 }
                             }
                         },
                         {
                             "term": {
                                 "name.keyword": {
                                     "value": "{{query_name}}",
                                     "boost": 2.0
                                 }
                             }
                         },
                         {
                             "match_phrase": {
                                 "name": "{{query_name}}"
                             }
                         }                         
                     ],
                     "minimum_should_match": 1
                 }
             },
             "functions": [{
                     "field_value_factor": {
                         "field": "weight",
                         "missing": 0
                     }
                 },
                 {
                     "field_value_factor": {
                         "field": "viewCount",
                         "modifier": "ln1p",
                         "missing": 0
                     },
                     "weight":2
                 }
             ],
             "score_mode": "sum",
             "boost_mode": "sum"
         }
     }     
 }
```

_cat indices

```
health status index               uuid                   pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
green  open   company             KTngnM6ASD-_KdU0FFAWRA   1   0  102120019     24166489     47.5gb         47.5gb
```

Comment: it depends on your use case, I guess. Could you provide some more details? For example, why not just reduce the size of the query response, or why not use scroll?

Comment: I just want to speed up the query performance, it's not related to pagination. Currently, even the first page with 20 results is very slow.

Comment: in that case, before changing the default configuration settings if your internals, you should focus on improving your mapping or query. what have you tried and didn’t work? also, replicas may help with search performance

Comment: [The definition of `max_result_window`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules.html#dynamic-index-settings) is `The maximum value of from + size for searches to this index` so lowering this value is only meaningful in the context of pagination. As @glenacota mentioned, you should probably show your query and mappings as there's probably more to be gained improving those before messing up with your index settings.